# How to display data in ejs view from ajax resultset when called in the view

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have an empty `ejs` view but I would like to display the result set of the ajax call that I am calling in the `ejs` view

```
<script>
 // Fetch 
  $.ajax(`/x`).done(function(data, textStatus, xhr){
console.log(data);
console.log(textStatus);
console.log(xhr);      
  });

</script>
<!-- how do I loop the data received from above and display the content here? -->
```

I am not sure how to do this.

**UPDATE**

here is what I have now. Is there any neater way to do this instead of appending as html?

```
<script>
  const gId = '<%= gId %>';

  // Fetch the current users c here from `/g/${gId }/c `
  $.ajax(`/g/${gId }/c `).done(function(data, textStatus, xhr){
    var c = '';
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
      console.log(index);
      console.log(value)
      c += '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"><div><img class="col-sm-12 col-md-11" src="'+value.image+'" /></div><div class="text-center"><input name="card" id="card" type="checkbox" value="'+value.value+'" /> Discard</div></div>';
    });

    $('#c ').append('<div class="row"><div class="row col-sm-12">'+c +'</div><div class="col-xs-2"></div></div>');

    $('#c ').append('<button type="submit">c </button>');
  });

  const checkExchangeStatus = function(){
    $.ajax(`/g/${gId}/allExchanged`).done(function(data, textStatus, xhr){
      if (xhr.status !== 202) { // not pending
        document.location = `/g/${gId}/result`;
      }
    })
  }

  setInterval(checkExchangeStatus, 1000);
</script>
<form method="POST" action="/g/<%= gId %>/exchange">
<div id="c ">
</div>
<div>
<br/>gId : <%= gId %>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with ejs. ejs is server-side javascript. You have to use vanilla javascript.

Comment: im confused. do you mean i have to loop inside the ajax and display inside a div. can i not access the data using `<% %>` outside the script tag?

Comment: ejs code like `<% %>` is executed on server and rendered as html. So you cant use ejs code with ajax requests.

Answer (score 1):

> "ejs code like <% %> is executed on server and rendered as html. So you can't use ejs code with ajax requests."

What you can do is make an ajax call, then alter your html page with jQuery.

I have an empty ejs view but I would like to display the result set of the ajax call that I am calling in the ejs view.

```
<script>
  $.ajax(`/x`).done(function(data, textStatus, xhr){
    console.log(data); //I am assuming this prints
      $('#someID').html(data);
  });
</script>
```

I don't know what results you are expecting, or what your html looks like. If you update your question with more code I can assist you further.

Comment: @shorif2000 can you provide an example of what you *want* the html to look like?  I don't understand what you are looking for exactly.